Pass optional argument containing spaces to shell command
How to safely pass an optional argument to some shell command in Bash that may contain spaces but also might not be given at all?
I have a script that may or may not receive a datetime string like 2024-09-19 12:34:56 in an environment variable. My scripts then calls the date command and only if the string is given should pass it like date "--date=2024-09-19 12:34:56" or otherwise escaping any shell meta characters. date from coreutils would also accept the string now but my target platform is the official Docker Hub image bash which is a busybox userland plus bash where I need to omit the argument altogether.
I do not want to support multiple args. So I don’t use "$@". I know and already successfully used printf %q but can’t get this to work:
for ENV_VAR in '' '2024-09-19 12:34:56'
do
    args=""
    [ -n "$ENV_VAR" ] && args="--date=$( printf %q "$ENV_VAR" )"
    date --utc $args +%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ
done

Result so far when running the code with bash -x:
+ for ENV_VAR in '' '2024-09-19 12:34:56'
+ args=
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ date +%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ
20240919T181953Z
+ for ENV_VAR in '' '2024-09-19 12:34:56'
+ args=
+ '[' -n '2024-09-19 12:34:56' ']'
++ printf %q '2024-09-19 12:34:56'
+ args='2024-09-19\ 12:34:56'
+ date '2024-09-19\' 12:34:56 +%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ
date: extra operand ‘12:34:56’
Try 'date --help' for more information.

It looks to me like $args is built correctly but it’s not correctly interpolated. Usually escaping strings like "$args" has long become part of my flesh and blood but in this case I need empty $args to just vanish instead of being an empty string argument.

Populate (or not) an array, then pass that as arguments: args=(); … && args+=(…); command … "${args[@]}" …

Or use an "alternate value" expansion, like ${ENV_VAR:+"--date=$ENV_VAR"}.
